# IFRAMEのリクエストによる親ドメインや接続元IPの取得

Tags: http

IFRAMEでリクエストを受けた際に

偽装などをされずにIFRAMEを埋め込んだ親ドメインの情報をリクエストから確認することは可能ですか？出来るとしたらどの情報を取得すれば良いでしょうか？もし、これらが不可能であれば、IFRAMEがどのドメインからもしくは、誰から埋め込まれたか確認するための方法が別にないか教えて欲しいです。
また、ユーザーの接続元外部IPを同じく確認することは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Referer: ヘッダ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP%E3%83%AA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%83%A9)があります。
しかし、条件によってはこれは付きません。
例えば`iframe`タグの`referrerpolicy`で`Refere`が付かないように出来るようです。

ユーザのIPアドレスに関しては`iframe`によるアクセス特有の事情は特に無いと思います。

---

同ドメインであればJavaScriptの`window.parent`が使えます。念の為。
また、他者のページに自分のコンテンツを埋め込まれるのを避けたい場合は、[`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)というヘッダを使えます。